# Stripes over 3D objects using ColorRamp

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv

Basically my task is to generate Color Ramp over 3D model. My confusion is in term of 3D Texture Coordinate that does not rotate and also if I were to use MODULO, the modulation stays under 1 Blender Texture Coordinate Unit. Instead of nicely scaling.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If what you want is to scale the coordinates to a value between 0.0 through 1.0, try using _Generated_ coordniates instead of _Object_, and drop the _Modulo_ node. You may want to look at [Manipulate texture coordinates like a boss](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0) by Bartek Skorupa. I'd also recommend reading, or at least skimming, [Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) on Wikipedia, as it seems you're confused about what _Modulo_ actually does. This article talks about modulo for integers, but it can easily be extended to real numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use **Object** only if you have a good understanding of the applied scale of your mesh, and agree with the comment that for ease you can use **Generated**.

I believe that Modulo does not really help here (for your understanding's sake), as you are trying to segment the 0 TO 1 mapping that you are trying to achieve (You need to know how this works first).

When you take your Geometry, and get a mesh specific 0 (Lowest) & 1 (Highest), you want to keep that map, not destroy it with Modulo (Yet).

So for my first example I want to show you what that means to change it to an Add calculation instead, so you see what happens from 0 To 1.

[image: ColorRampZAxisMappingAddExampleAnimation]

Next You want to be sure when you introduce your Texture mapping node, that it connects to the vector inputs of all that would be affected by the rotation.

[image: ColorRampZAxisMappingTextureMappingExampleAnimation]

---

Now if you want to scale in a repeating striped way you could do this, and have the best of both worlds:

[image: ColorRampWithStriping]

Just play with the B/W color ramp & the Brick Texture scale factor for preference, Or re-introduce your Modulo as you see fit (Now that you understand how the Texture Mapping is working).